# Zend Navigation - Rendering a submenu

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I define all my pages in a XML file like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>
<nav>
    <dashboard>
        <label>Dashboard</label>
        <module>default</module>
        <controller>dashboard</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <title>Die Schaltzentrale</title>
    </dashboard>
    <user>
        <label>User</label> 
        <module>default</module>
        <controller>user</controller>   
        <action>index</action>
        <title>Verwaltung der Benutzer</title>

        <userList>                  
            <module>default</module>
            <controller>user</controller>   
            <action>index</action>
            <label>Userliste anzeigen</label>
        </userList>
        <newUser>
            <label>User anlegen</label> 
            <module>default</module>
            <controller>user</controller>   
            <action>new</action>
        </newUser>
        <editUser>
            <label>User bearbeiten</label>  
            <module>default</module>
            <controller>user</controller>   
            <action>edit</action>
        </editUser>
    </user>
</nav>  
</configdata>
```

In my bootstrap I setup my navigation like this:

```
    protected function _initNavigation()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml','nav');
        $view = $layout->getView();
        $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
        $view->navigation($navigation); 
        Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Navigation',$navigation);
    }
```

This setup enables me to render my main menu with the following lines:

```
$partial = array('menu.phtml', 'default');
$this->navigation()->menu()->setPartial($partial);
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->render();
```

So far so good. My problem is now to render a particular submenu. Let's say I want to render a menu with all actions of the user controller. I tried to render it with:

```
$page = $this->navigation()->findOneBy('controller','user');
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu($page);
```

But I got no output. I also tried to obtain an output by setting the minDepth or maxDepth option without any success. Has anyone a hind for me, how I can bring it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is very close. Change the findOneBy line to:

`$page = $this->navigation()->findOneBy('label','User');`

This will fetch all the pages under the User page.

I do not think it is possible to find a page by controller.

[edit]

I have modified your xml by adding a 'pages' section under user. This tells Zend Navigation that userList, newUser and editUser are sub-pages of user:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>
<nav>
    <dashboard>
        <label>Dashboard</label>
        <module>default</module>
        <controller>dashboard</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <title>Die Schaltzentrale</title>
    </dashboard>
    <user>
        <label>User</label> 
        <module>default</module>
        <controller>user</controller>   
        <action>index</action>
        <title>Verwaltung der Benutzer</title>
        <pages>
            <userList>
                <module>default</module>
                <controller>user</controller>   
                <action>index</action>
                <label>Userliste anzeigen</label>
            </userList>                
            <newUser>
                <label>User anlegen</label> 
                <module>default</module>
                <controller>user</controller>   
                <action>new</action>
            </newUser>
            <editUser>
                <label>User bearbeiten</label>  
                <module>default</module>
                <controller>user</controller>   
                <action>edit</action>
            </editUser>
        </pages>
    </user>
</nav>  
</configdata>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I found the findOneBy('controller') approach in this tutorial [link](http://www.brandonsavage.net/making-zend_navigation-useful/). If I search for a label instead a controller I actually obtain an output. But I only get the main menu. It seems to me, that Zend dosen't read in the XML structure correctly.

Comment: It could be that the xml is wrong. I have updated my answer. Please try the modified xml.

Comment: With your suggestion I am able to obtain an output. But I have still one problem with it. Let's say I have one more controller called 'device' with two more pages. If I render my submenu now I get a menu with all pages, which have a depth of one. But not separated by the particular controller. So I get a menu with all links from user and device, although I search for a particular label. It seems to me, that there is still something wrong with my XML.